# Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$milibro' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php

Tengo un error cuando llamo al método setTitulo y no consigo averiguar cuál es? Alguien lo sabe?

```
    <?php 

 include "includes/conexionBD.php";


class Libro {

 private $id;
  public $titulo;
  public $autor;
  private $editorial;
  private $anyo;
  private $genero;
  private $portada;
  private $sinopsis;
  private $precio;
  private $ventas;
  private $enlaceBD;
  private $datosSelect;

//Contructor de la clase libro

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->enlaceBD = $enlaceBD;

      if($id == null)      $this->id = $this->ObtenerSiguienteID();
      else                 $this->id = $id;


      $this->id = $id;
      $this->titulo =$titulo;
      $this->autor = $autor;
      $this->editorial = $editorial;
      $this->anyo = $anyo;
      $this->genero = $genero;
      $this->portada = $portada;
      $this->sinopsis = $sinopsis;
      $this->precio = $precio;
      $this->ventas = $ventas;






  }




  //Getter y Setters

  public function setId($id) {

          $this->id = $id;
  }

    public function getId() { 
        return $this->id; 
    } 

    public function setTitulo($titulo) {
        if (is_string($titulo)) {
          $this->titulo = $titulo;
        }
    }

    public function getTitulo() { 
        return $this->titulo; 
    } 

?>                                            




  <?php 

include "clase.php";
//instaciar la clase 
  $milibro = new Libro; 
echo "Propietario: " . $milibro->setTitulo("hola") . "<br />";

  ?>
```

Comment: ¿Ese es un mismo archivo? Si es así, ¿qué hacen ahí estas dos líneas: `$milibro = new Libro;` y esta `echo "Propietario: " . $milibro->setTitulo("hola") . "<br />";` ¿?  Eso es para instanciar la clase fuera de ella. La clase es como un molde del que echas mano para construir instancias de objetos con `new`. Al parecer quieres instanciar la clase dentro de ella misma ¿? Además estás poniendo a `setTitulo` dentro de un `echo` como si ese método devolviese algo... El método `setTitulo` asigna un título al libro, si quieres mostrarlo tienes que usar `getTitulo`una vez lo hayas seteado.

Comment: No, esas dos líneas están dentro de un archivo index.php :                                
<?php 

include "clase.php";
//instaciar la clase 
  $milibro = new Libro; 
echo "Propietario: " . $milibro->setTitulo("hola") . "<br />";

Comment: Pusiste todo el código junto. Debes separarlo por archivos y poner el contenido completo, de lo contrario no se puede revisar porque es un error de sintaxis en alguna parte.

Comment: Ya lo he puesto

Comment: Tienes que instanciar la clase así : `$milibro = new Libro();` Te faltan los paréntesis.

Comment: Me sigue dando este error -. Missing argument 1 for Libro::__construct(), called in C:\Xampp\htdocs\index1.php on line 6 and defined in

Comment: Está mal planteada tu clase. ¿La puedes cambiar ?

Comment: Sí, la puedo cambiar

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88845/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-juan).

Comment: Primero te falta un `}` para cerrar la clase segundo en el constructor desde `$this->titulo` hasta `$this->ventas = $ventas;` debes quitarlo eso no esta haciendo nada saludos

Comment: Juan acabo de publicar [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967) que trata sobre el mapeo de clases con [una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233095/29967) donde se explica con un ejemplo en línea cómo se hace.