# ¿Como se mapea el resultado de una consulta SQL a una clase en PHP usando PDO y cómo se usa?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, buenas-prácticas

En los días pasados vi varias preguntas donde se cometían errores graves en el diseño de clases.

En al menos dos casos, se incluía como miembro de la clase un objeto que era la conexión a la base de datos. Otra cosa que se hacía era: dentro del constructor de la clase  conectar a la base de datos, hacer una consulta y llenar con cada columna obtenida las propiedades de la clase.

En algunos casos eran clases relacionadas y toda esa lógica en el constructor complicaba las cosas.

Dicho esto: ¿existe una forma más fácil de mapear los resultados de una consulta a una clase, para evitar tener que crear una clase como esta:

```
class Actor {
    private $actor_id;
    private $actor_nombre;
    private $actor_apellido;
    private $actor_sexo;
    private $last_update;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
        $strSQL="SELECT * FROM actor_20171002 WHERE actor_id = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($strSQL);
        $arrParams=array($id);
        $stmt ->execute($arrParams);
        while ( $row= $stmt->fetch(PDO::PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ) 
        {
            $this->actor_id=$row->actor_id;
            $this->actor_nombre=$row->actor_nombre;
            $this->actor_apellido=$row->actor_apellido;
            $this->actor_sexo=$row->actor_sexo;
            $this->last_update=$row->last_update;
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->actor_nombre;
    }
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->actor_apellido;
    }
    public function getLastUpdate()
    {
        return new DateTime($this->last_update);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente, la práctica implementada en la clase `Actor` de la pregunta es descabellada. ¿Alguien conoce a un `Actor` que en tanto que actor lleve para donde quiera una conexión a la base de datos? Ninguno, ni siquiera el protagonista de Matrix.

Siempre que se cree una instancia de `Actor` ocurrirá el código que hay en el constructor:

- conectar a la base de datos
- lanzar una consulta
- en base a los datos traídos llenar las propiedades de la clase

Si en alguna parte del programa se requiere usar el molde que es la clase `Actor` para llenarlo de otra forma (a mano por ejemplo con `$actor->setName("Neo");`), ¿qué sentido tendría toda la lógica que quiso implementarse en el constructor?

Además, como indica el título de la pregunta, hay formas de mapear resultados de la base de datos a una clase de PHP.

Uno de los *fetch styles*  de PDO es el llamado **[`PDO::FETCH_CLASS`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)** el cual:

> ... devuelve una nueva instancia de la clase solicitada, haciendo
> corresponder las columnas del conjunto de resultados con los nombres
> de las propiedades de la clase, y llamando al constructor después, a
> menos que también se proporcione `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`. Si
> fetch_style incluye `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` (por ejemplo,
> `PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`), entonces el nombre de la
> clase se determina a partir del valor de la primera columna.

Sabiendo esto, es posible entonces liberar nuestra clase de toda la lógica que se quiso implementar en el constructor, dejando la clase como lo que es, un molde para fabricar objetos del tipo `Actor` y nada más, trasladando la lógica el contexto de uso de la clase.

Es tan simple como esto:

1. Conectar a la base de datos
2. Lanzar la consulta
3. Asignar al conjunto de resultados el *fetch mode* `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` indicando a qué clase se mapearán los resultados.
4. Aplicar el método `fetch` sobre un objeto dato. Ese objeto recibirá una clase `Actor` con los datos de cada columna asignado a su miembro respectivo.

Veamos un ejemplo funcional:

#### Clase `Actor`

```
class Actor {

    private $actor_id;
    private $actor_nombre;
    private $actor_apellido;
    private $actor_sexo;
    private $last_update;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->actor_nombre;
    }
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->actor_apellido;
    }
    public function getLastUpdate()
    {
        return new DateTime($this->last_update);
    }
    public function setName($actor_nombre)
    {
        $this->actor_nombre=$actor_nombre;
    }
    /*Otros setter*/
}
```

---

#### Código en un contexto cualquiera de nuestro programa

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
$strSQL="SELECT * FROM actor_20171002 WHERE actor_id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($strSQL);
$arrParams=array(2);
$stmt ->execute($arrParams);

/*Preparamos para mapear el resultado*/
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Actor');
$actor = $stmt->fetch();
```

*That's all!* Ya tenemos en `$actor` una instancia de nuestra clase llena con los datos que trajo la consulta.

Vamos a revisarla:

```
var_dump($actor);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(Actor)#3 (5) {
  ["actor_id":"Actor":private]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["actor_nombre":"Actor":private]=>
  string(6) "Marlon"
  ["actor_apellido":"Actor":private]=>
  string(6) "Brando"
  ["actor_sexo":"Actor":private]=>
  string(1) "M"
  ["last_update":"Actor":private]=>
  string(19) "2017-10-23 10:08:02"
}
```

Eso significa que podemos valernos de cualquier método/propiedad de la clase. Aquí usamos los *getter*  para mostrar la información:

```
echo "Nombre:\t {$actor->getName()}\n";
echo "Nombre:\t {$actor->getLastName()}\n";
echo "Update:\t {$actor->getLastUpdate()->format("F j, Y, g:i a")}";
```

**Salida:**

```
Nombre:  Marlon
Nombre:  Brando
Update:  October 23, 2017, 10:08 am
```

Claro está, también podemos modificar el objeto, mediante sus métodos *setter*  por ejemplo:

```
$actor->setName("Neo");
```

---

#### Fiddle

Aquí se puede ver un <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/n0ex-rw0g)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas sobre el código. Hay que pulsar **`Run - F9`** en la página para ver el resultado.

Comment: Buenas @A. Cedano, estoy intentando seguir tu consejo pero hay una cosa que no me queda del todo claro. En el ejemplo que propones, si el actor, por ejemplo, necesita actuar en una película ¿la función actuar no se encontraría dentro de la clase? ¿esto no provocaría quizá algo de desorden en el sistema?

Saludos

Comment: Porque claro, lo que propones sería crear las instancias de PDO desde el controlador, verdad? o podríamos crear una instancia a PDO desde cada método de la clase en la que se necesite?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía tanto el hecho de *actuar*, como la instancia de PDO que se cree, pertenece al *contexto*, por tanto, ambas cosas deberían estar en el controlador (cuando hablo del *contexto*  entiéndase *controlador*). Si piensas de forma concienzuda un modelo orientado a objetos, *actuar* no debería pertenecer jamás a la clase `Actor`, por un hecho muy simple: no todos los actores *actúan*, por ejemplo, un autor fallecido ya no actúa, el método *actúar*  por tanto pertenecería a otro ámbito, quizá a una clase `Película` o a una clase padre llamada `Obra` de la que extendería...

Comment: ... `Pelicula` así como otras clases que implican actores como `Documental`, `MiniSerie`, `Novela`, `ObraTeatral`, `DibujoAnimado`, `Comedia`, etc, etc. Pongo este ejemplo sobre todo para abrir horizontes y puedas entender de qué hablo cuando hablo de *contexto*. Así mismo, poner una conexión PDO en cualquier método de cualquier clase es un grave error, porque puede haber contextos en los que no necesites una conexión PDO. Imaginemos ***un contexto*** en el que la clase `Actor` o cualquier otra sería alimentada por una API, un archivo externo u otro. ¿Qué sentido tendría PDO en la clase?

Comment: Muchas Gracias @A.Cedano y disculpa mi desconocimiento pero aún no veo del todo clara la cuestión. Entiendo lo que quieres decir. Pero propongo otro ejemplo. Imaginemos una clase, "Artículo" en la que cada instancia quiera tener un método llamado crear. Este método necesita hacer una consulta para insertar una fila en la DB. Cómo propondrías hacerlo?en el contexto?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Es que en ese caso la clase no necesita un método `crear`, ese método ya lo tiene, que es el constructor de la clase. Quizá, dependiendo del contexto, la clase podría tener un método `insert`, que recibiría en parámetro la conexión a la base de datos y haría la inserción, pero la clase debería ser alimentada previamente. Supongamos que los datos a insertar vienen de un archivo: 1º. Lees el archivo, 2º. Creas la instancia de la clase y la informas con los datos obtenidos en 1; 3º Conectas a la BD; 4º Invocas `insertar` pasándole la conexión; 4º. Ejecutas la inserción...

Comment: ...otro escenario posible sería tener una clase que maneje la conexión, con un método `insert` al que le pasas: 1º. La tabla, 2º los datos, 3º haces la inserción. El *quid* para determinar cómo tienes que organizar los objetos es pensar siempre que estos tienen que ser lo menos dependientes posible, y para esto siempre ayuda imaginar varios contextos o casos de uso. Como ya dije antes, no siempre en un caso de uso hará falta la conexión a la base de datos por ejemplo, porque los objetos de esa clase pueden llenarse desde otras fuentes que no es la base de datos.

Comment: Ok @A.Cedano, creo que lo entiendo. Según propones, la conexión a la DB siempre debería realizarse desde el contexto (el controlador). ¿Pero entonces no provocaría una incoherencia con el MVC? Según tengo entendido, en este modelo, es la capa Model la que realiza la consulta a la DB

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía también es correcto lo que dices. Quizá en el modelo se puede tener una clase que gestione la conexión a la base de datos. Luego habría que ver la forma más adecuada de conectar los objetos: la clase `Conexion` con la clase `Actor`. Lo que sí me queda claro es que un objeto `Conexion` no pinta nada dentro de la clase `Actor` ni dentro de ninguna otra clase, porque `Conexion` no es parte constitutiva de un `Actor`, es un objeto *utilitario* que se puede usar o no, dependiendo del origen de datos. Yo realmente no he trabajado en proyectos grandes, pero meter la conexión ...

Comment: ...dentro de las clases del modelo, aparte de que tienes que hacerlo en cada clase, no respetaría la finalidad de las mismas, si éstas se piensan como *moldes* para construir objetos de ese tipo. A lo sumo, podrías invocar la conexión desde un método determinado de la clase. Por ejemplo yo tengo montado una API muy sencilla al estilo MVC, donde el archivo `index.php` hace de controlador y en las clases del modelo tengo varios tipos de método, uno obtiene los datos desde el servidor (`getFromServer()`) consultando a la base de datos...

Comment: ... otro obtiene los datos desde firebase (`getFromFirebase()`). En ese caso, la conexión se invoca únicamente desde `getFromServer()` porque solamente en ese caso se necesita una conexión a la base de datos. Ambos métodos son parte de las diferentes clases del modelo. ¿Es correcto o incorrecto? No sabría decirte, tampoco soy un experto en MVC. Quizá para ciertos casos MVC no es la mejor opción y se podría optar por otro paradigma.

Comment: Genial @A.Cedano, entiendo lo que dices. Ahora estoy empezando un proyecto (solo para practicar) y estoy teniendo en cuenta tus consejos. Lo que se me ha ocurrido para no caer en redundancia con PDO es crear un atributo conexion dentro de la clase Uno (por Ej.) y, aparte una clase Conexion. Luego, desde el contexto, creo un objeto Uno y, en caso de necesitar hacer la consulta, rellenaría el atributo conexion de Uno con la funcion conectar() de Conexion. Así no llamaría a la conexión en caso de no necesitarla y, al mismo tiempo, respeto los principios de MVC. O eso creo   :D