# ¿Como se puede añadir una clase abstracta y las clases que heredan a una base de datos? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, clase-abstracta

Quiero saber si es posible y como se crearía una tabla partiendo de una clase abstracta y otras tabla partiendo de una clase que hereda de la clase abstracta.

Os pongo en situación, tengo una clase abstracta Usuarios y de esta heredan otras tres clases, profesor, alumno y secretario, la clase abstracta tiene como atributos todos los datos que definen a un usuario y las clases que heredan tienen un par de atributos específicos.

Y mi duda esta en si es posible y como puedo hacer para crear una base de datos donde pueda insertar usuarios, profesores,alumnos y secretarios y que luego al mostrar los datos de, por ejemplo un alumno, me muestre también los atributos que le pertenecen como usuario.

Comment: Al leerte creo que estás planteando las cosas al revés: no debes crear una tabla partiendo de una clase, sino todo lo contrario, **crear tu clase en base a la tabla**. O sea, las clases deben expresar lo que existe en tus tablas, dando por supuesto que al diseñar las tablas has analizado a conciencia el modelo de datos, cómo debe relacionarse cada entidad, etc. Luego incluso puedes mapear los resultados de una consulta en tu clase, [como se muestra en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967).

Comment: entiendo lo que dices, primero definir como será la base de datos y ya a partir de ella es cuando crearía la app en php, correcto? pero... se prodría utilizar clases abstractas? es que, por ejemplo, imagina un secretario,un profe y un alumno tienen nombre,apellidos etc y para no crear tanto código duplicado como haría en la bd la clase abstracta usuario y que al mapear sus datos en la app me dijera si es profe, alumno o secretario?

Comment: Correcto. Es diseñando las tablas donde tendrás que decidir tu modelo de datos y la forma en que van a relacionarse las tablas para que no haya redundancia de datos. Partiendo de eso podrás entonces escribir cada `clase`. En las clases podrás tener miembros de otra clase, implementar herencia, etc. Si empiezas por diseñar clases para luego querer adaptar las tablas a ese diseño creo que lo tendrás mucho más complicado. Hay herramientas que permiten hacer 1º el diseño de clases, pero tendrías que aprender a usar esas herramientas, creo que es mejor empezar por las tablas.

Comment: Si empiezas diseñando las tablas verás cómo tus dudas irán siendo clarificadas. Tienes que partir de lo general a lo particular. La tabla base sería entonces `Persona`, en esa tabla irían las columnas que son comunes a todos los otros tipos, o sea, **todo lo que tienen en común `Profesor, Alumno, Secretario`, por decir algo, todos ellos tienen `nombre, apellido, sexo, fecha_nacimiento...` todo eso iría en la tabla `Persona`. Luego, ¿qué es propio **únicamente** de un `Profesor`, `Alumno`, `Secretario` ... teniendo en cuenta que muchas de esas propiedades serían parte de otras tablas ...

Comment: ... en forma de llave foránea por ejemplo (aquí entraría el principio de **no redundancia de datos**) que debe quedar muy bien definido y clarificado en el diseño de tus tablas. Toda la complejidad del asunto reside ahí, y cuando tengas eso, la definición de cada clase es lo de menos, porque sólo vas a reflejar en las clases la realidad misma de tus datos donde ellos existen realmente que es en la base de datos. La clase podemos decir es una representación en forma de objeto de una realidad que ya existe. De hecho esa es una de las grandes ventajas de la POO, que refleja la realidad.