# Object of class Productos could not be converted to string

Tags: php

Mi codigo me tira este error "Object of class Productos could not be converted to string". Ocurre en la linea cuando hago el new Productos (No me deja copiar esa parte del codigo aca )

Necesitaría ayuda para obtener los atributos de mi clase que provienen del query, ¿es un problema de FETCH::PDO ? ¿ Es el query? ¿ O es la asignación de la variable del query a los atributos de la instancia de  "Productos"? Cabe destacar que lo que se encuentra en sql_comida lo traemos desde un simple query a una base de datos.

```
<?php
class Productos{

    private $nombre;
    private $precio;
    private $stock;
    private $rutaImagen;

    public function __construct($nombreIngresado, $precioIngresado, $stockIngresado, $rutaImagenIngresada){
        $this->nombre = $nombreIngresado;
        $this->precio = $precioIngresado;
        $this->stock = $stockIngresado;
        $this->rutaImagen = $rutaImagenIngresada;
    }
    public function getNombre(){
        return $this->nombre;
    }
    public function getPrecio(){
        return $this->precio;
    }
    public function getStock(){
        return $this->stock;
    }
    public function getRutaImagen(){
        return $this->rutaImagen;
    }
    public function mostrarImagen(){
        echo '<img src="'. getRutaImagen() .'" alt="'. getNombre() . '">';
    }
    public function mostrarNombre(){
        echo '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">'. getNombre() .'</a></h3>';
    }
    public function mostrarPrecio(){
        echo '<h4 class="product-price">'. getPrecio() .'</h4>';
    }
    public function mostrarStock(){
        echo '<p class="product-stock">Stock: '. getStock() .'</p>';    
    }
    public function mostrarInformacionBasica(){
        $this->mostrarNombre();
        $this->mostrarPrecio();
        $this->mostrarStock();
    }
}
?>
```

-

```
<?php while($auxiliar = $sql_comida-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
                                <?= $comida = new Productos($auxiliar["Nombre"], $auxiliar["Precio"], $auxiliar["Stock"], $auxiliar["RutaImagen"])?>
                            <!-- product -->
                                <div class="product">
                                    <div class="product-img">
                                        <?= $comida->mostrarImagen(); ?>
                                        <div class="product-label"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="product-body">
                                        <?= $comida->mostrarInformacionBasica(); ?>                     
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if($comida["Stock"] > 0) : ?>
                                        <div class="add-to-cart">
                                            <button id="botonAgregar" class="add-to-cart-btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Agregar al carrito</button>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>    
                                </div>
                                <!-- /product -->
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. No sé si sabes que en PDO es muy fácil mapear los resultados de una consulta a una clase concreta. Al hacerlo, los miembros de la clase toman el valor de sus columnas respectivas en la tabla. Puedes revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967) y la respuesta. Creo que necesitas algo parecido para este caso.

Comment: Es un simple `<?=` inadecuado que anda por ahí, mira la respuesta de Franz Garcia.

Answer (score 2):

el problema es que tratas de hacer un echo de un objeto, en la siguiente linea cambia el tag de apertura `"<?="` por `"<?php"` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php $comida = new Productos($auxiliar["Nombre"], $auxiliar["Precio"], $auxiliar["Stock"], $auxiliar["RutaImagen"])?>
```

Recuerda que `<?=` es lo mismo que `<?php echo`, posiblemente querías usar la apertura con *short tag* `<?`, en cualquier caso, ambas formas son desaconsejadas (incluso se suelen deshabilitar). Acostúmbrate a usar `<?php` siempre para evitar confusiones.