# Enviar datos json (array) a mi base de datos Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, json, array, eloquent

Al tener todas mis clases agregadas apreto el boton enviar en el cual se envia el json y hace un submit a un formulario (se ve en el ajax que esta mas abajo) el cual se llena antes de ingresar al modal que se ve mas abajo en la imagen.

Estoy intentando enviar los datos de un array a mi base de datos, el array lo obtengo mediante la decodificacion de un json que recibo mediante ajax, el cual lo creo a partir de un fnGetData() de DataTable.

Recibo correctamente el json en el controlador y al decodificarlo, me queda un array principal en el cual tengo muchos arrays, los cuales, cada uno es una clase (cada clase es un row de la datatable)

Para dejar todo mas claro, esta es mi tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma envio el json a mi controlador

```
$.ajax({
  url:"{{ route('alumno.horario') }}",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(p),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success : function(){
    $('#alumno-frm').submit(); // ENVIO FORMULARIO DE ALUMNO MEDIANTE SU RUTA
    $("#tablaAgregados").DataTable().clear().draw();
  },
  error: function(){
    //-----
  }
});
```

De esta forma recibo y decodifico el json en mi controlador

```
public function storeHorario(Request $request){ // GUARDAR HORARIO
      $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
      dump($data);
      // return json_encode($data); 
   }
```

y este es el resultado del json decodificado

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:10 [
    0 => 1
    1 => "20/11/2019"
    2 => "18:13"
    3 => "120 minutos"
    4 => "NOMBRE PROFESOR"
    5 => "Toyota Yaris 2A-1S-D2"
    6 => "<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger elevation-1 btn_eliminar">Quitar</button>"
    7 => "47"
    8 => "6"
  ]
  1 => array:10 [
    0 => 2
    1 => "20/11/2019"
    2 => "18:13"
    3 => "120 minutos"
    4 => "NOMBRE PROFESOR"
    5 => "Toyota Yaris 2A-1S-D2"
    6 => "<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger elevation-1 btn_eliminar">Quitar</button>"
    7 => "47"
    8 => "6"
  ]
]
```

intente enviar una sola clase a mi horario de esta forma, pero no me funciona (el ajax me devuelve error)

```
public function storeHorario(Request $request){ // GUARDAR HORARIO
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $array_data = $data['0'];

    $dato2 = $array_data['0'];
    $dato3 = $array_data['1'];
    $dato4 = $array_data['2'];
    $dato5 = 'practica';
    $dato6 = $array_data['3'];
    $dato7 = $array_data['7'];
    $dato8 = $array_data['8'];

    $horario = horarioModel::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'clase' => $dato2,
            'fecha' => $dato3,
            'hora' => $dato4,
            'tipo' => $dato5,
            'minutos_bloque' => $dato6,
            'id_profesor' => $dato7,
            'id_vehiculo' => $dato8
        ]
    );
        return json_encode($data);
   }
```

Lo que necesito es capturar los datos 0,1,2,3,7,8 y 9 de cada array y enviarlos como una clase de mi horario a sus respectivos campos de la tabla.

***Modelo de tabla horario***

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class horarioModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'horario';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_horario';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_horario',
        'clase',
        'fecha',
        'hora',
        'tipo',
        'minutos_bloque',
        'id_curso',
        'id_profesor',
        'id_alumno',
        'id_vehiculo',
        'id_estado'
    ];
}
```

Comment: ¿Laravel no tiene algo para mapear el JSON a la clase directamente? Eso existe por ejemplo en PDO ([ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967)), supongo que Laravel tendrá algo parecido.

Comment: Cual es el error? mira en `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Subire el log con el error que me aparece, que la verdad no le encuntro mucho sentido al error que me aparece

Comment: estás intentando insertar `20/11/2019` en el campo fecha. que tipo de dato es el campo fecha de tu database, y si es tipo `date`, con qué formato?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ por eso mismo encontraba raro, por que el campo fecha esta como varchar en mi base de datos, es mas, no tengo ningun campo tipo date a excepcion de los timestamp (create o update)

Comment: @A.Cedano la verdad es que lo desconozco

Comment: 'id_horario' es la llave primaria y autoincrementable? podrías mostrar la migración de esa tabla? y el modelo también si es posible? Puedes probar también con `horarioModel::updateOrCreate(['id_horario' => $dato1?: NULL],[...]);`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no utilizo migraciones, adjunto el modelo de mi tabla a la pregunto, y respecto al id_horario, esta como autoincrement

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ de hecho intente enviar una clase colocandole el id_horario manuelamente en el controlador y de esta forma si me guardo la clase, al parecer el updateOrCreate no me esta detectando el dato como vacio

Comment: Sí puede ser que la database no esté tomando el string vacío com NULL, por eso lo que te decía en el comentario anterior. También quitaría 'id_horario' del array $fillable en el modelo, no es necesario si ya está definida como primaryKey

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ vale, tiene bastante sentido eso, lo hice y efectivamente funciono el registro, ahora viene lo que preguntaba realmente, como poder enviar las clases, por que ahora solo logre enviar 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más simple sería iterar sobre el array con un foreach. Siguiendo la lógica con la que estás ya trabajando, se me ocurre algo así:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent());
foreach($data as $array_data) {
    $dato2 = $array_data['0'];
    $dato3 = $array_data['1'];
    $dato4 = $array_data['2'];
    $dato5 = 'practica';
    $dato6 = $array_data['3'];
    $dato7 = $array_data['7'];
    $dato8 = $array_data['8'];

    horarioModel::updateOrCreate(
        ['id_horario' => $dato1?: NULL],
        [
            'clase' => $dato2,
            'fecha' => $dato3,
            'hora' => $dato4,
            'tipo' => $dato5,
            'minutos_bloque' => $dato6,
            'id_profesor' => $dato7,
            'id_vehiculo' => $dato8
        ]
    );
}
return json_encode($data);
```

Solo ten en cuenta de que si son muchos los datos, hacer queries dentro de un foreach es intenso para la BD, por lo que habría que buscar otra manera que no sea con updateOrCreate.

Comment: FUNCIONO!!! muchas gracias!! me guarda correctamente la cantidad de clases necesarias! me ayudaste con todos los problemas! gracias!

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo!, hemos estado pensando tanto por eso!! jaja (soy compañero del que pregunto)! enserio estamos agradecidos contigo!!

Comment: Vale, me alegro que les haya servido ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ''` tu `DB` espera un formato `Fecha` y le estas pasando `String`

```
date   "20/11/2019"   => "2019-11-2019"

datetime "20/11/2019" => "2019-11-2019 00:00:00"
```

el formato debe se `Y-m-d`

Comment: realmente ese error aparecia por el id_horario, el cual no me detectaba como vacio el array que le pasaba, pero ese punto ya eta solucionado, ahora estoy con el verdadero problema que explicaba en la pregunta, el como enviar todas las clases