# insertar valores de un array en laravel

Tags: laravel, json

estoy tratando de insertar valores de un array en una api en Laravel,

el array es miembros, y quiero insertar la asistencia de varios miembros en la base de datos mysql

```
   $asistencias=json_decode($request->miembros);


  for($i=0;$i<count($asistencias);$i++){
       $asistencia = new Asistencia();
       $asistencia->id_informe = $id; 
       $asistencia->valor=$asistencias[$i]->valor_miembro; 
       $asistencia->cod_persona=$asistencias[$i]- 
       >cod_persona_miembro;
       $asistencia->save();
  }
```

este es el objeto json con los datos, lo envió a traves de postman

```
  { "miembros": [
    {
        "valor_miembro": 1,
       "cod_persona_miembro": "122"
    },
    {
         "valor_miembro": 2,
    "cod_persona_miembro": "44336"
    }
]}
```

el mensaje de error que me aparece en postman  es el siguiente

```
  "message": "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given",
```

no se que estoy haciendo mal, primera vez que recorro un array y subo esos datos a la bd

Comment: Está esperando que el primer parámetro que pases en json_decode($request->miembros) sea un String y no un array como lo es ahora

Comment: pero lo que necesito es poder insertar el array en la bd, sabes como lo podria hacer?

Comment: Prueba a usar la funcion implode para pasar el array a string

Comment: $asistencias=json_decode($request->miembros); `o cambie a $asistencias=json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` foreach ($asistenciasas $asistencia) { $valor = $asistencia['valor']; Asistencia::updateOrCreate( [ 'valor' => $valor, ] ); } Intente algo asi o puede ver esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310179/enviar-datos-json-array-a-mi-base-de-datos-laravel-5-8