# Problema de conexion al hacer dos consultas a mysql por PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, poo

Tengo dos clases (usuario y anuncio) y quiero obtener datos independientes (O sea, que no tienen FK en común) de las dos tablas con los mismos nombres que las clases. Desde las dos tablas tengo una función de inicialización de PDO. 
La cuestión es ¿No puedo enviar dos conexiones al mismo tiempo? 
Es decir, si creo un objeto usuario y otro anuncio y, por ejemplo, quiero mostrar en pantalla los datos de ambas tablas ¿es normal que me dé error?

```
<?php
$usuario = new Usuario;
$anuncio = new Anuncio;
$usuario->obtener_datos();
$anuncio->obtener_datos();
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias 
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es normal que te de error, pues es el archivo Conexion.php lo has declarado dos veces mediante la palabra reservada `require('Conexion.php')` en la clase Usuario.php y Anuncio.php

Te recomiendo colocarle dentro de ambas clases la palabra reservada `require_once('Conexion.php')` en lugar de `require('Conexion.php')` pues no sabes si en un futuro ocupes primero la clase Anuncio u otras clases. PHP verificará si el archivo ya ha sido requerido y si es así, no se requiere de nuevo.

Fuente: [require_once PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php)

Comment: Gracias Edgard!

Comment: Recuerda que require, require_once haces que el escript que estas solicitando sea obligatorio en tu programa, en caso falle el script se detendrá y te dará error fatal. De lo contrario sucede con include e include_once que si luego falla por alguna razón el script no se detiene y solo te puede mostrar un warning.

Comment: Yo recomendaría lo contrario: **que no se requiera el archivo `Conexion.php` en ninguna de las dos clases**. ¿Por qué? Porque podría haber contextos en los que no se necesite una conexión. Imaginemos que el contexto evoluciona, se crea una API que devuelve un JSON a partir del cual se va a llenar una instancia de `Anuncio` o de `Usuario`... Ahí la conexión no serviría de nada. En la POO hay que pensar los objetos como en la vida real. ¿Un `Usuario` porta consigo **siempre** una conexión, nace con una conexión, es parte intrínseca de él? Pues no. Entonces, una conexión no deber ir dentro.

Answer (score 1):

No deberías requerir la conexión dentro de la clase `Usuario`, ni dentro de la clase `Anuncio`, ni dentro de ninguna clase.

Una clase tiene que ser pensada como un molde que sirve para fabricar objetos de ese tipo, independientemente del contexto desde el cual se fabrique.

La base de datos es solamente un contexto o escenario posible entre muchos. Imaginemos que el contexto en un futuro se diversifica, y los datos de `Usuario` o de cualquier otra clase se obtienen no solamente desde la base de datos, sino también desde una API en forma de JSON, o desde un WebService en forma de XML ... Cuando quieras tirar de la clase `Usuario` vas a tener que ir arrastrando siempre con la conexión, aún en aquellos contextos donde no la necesites.

Cuando se diseñan clases, tienes que preguntarte **qué es lo propio, lo intrínseco, lo que hacer *ser*  a esa clase (desde el punto de vista metafísico)**. Eso es lo único que debería haber en la clase `Usuario`. Todo lo demás debe crearse fuera, en el contexto donde se vaya a usar.

Ejemplo sencillo de una clase `User`:

```
class User {

    private $user_id;
    private $user_nombre;
    private $user_apellido;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->user_nombre;
    }
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->user_apellido;
    }
    public function setName($user_nombre)
    {
        $this->user_nombre=$user_nombre;
    }
    /*Otros setter*/
}
```

Como se puede ver, dentro de la clase no se crea ninguna conexión. La conexión debe crearse fuera, en el contexto. Además, cuando pones la conexión dentro, renuncias a una gran ventaja que tiene PDO, que es mapear un resultado a una clase<sup>1</sup>.

Veamos un ejemplo de uso contextual:

### Contexto 1: Base de Datos

```
require_once('Conexion.php');
$pdo = new PDO(); #Se supone que Conexion crea una instancia válida de PDO en el constructor
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$args=array(2);
$stmt ->execute($args);

/*Preparamos para mapear el resultado*/
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
$mUser = $stmt->fetch();
```

### Contexto 2: una API que devuelve JSON

```
$mJson=file_get_contents('https://miAPI/user/id/2');
```

Aquí `$mJson` sería un JSON con las mismas propiedades de tu clase `User` y podrías usar un mapeador propio o de terceros para, a partir de `$mJson` crear una instancia de la clase `User`. Así, podemos imaginar cualquier otro contexto, como un WebService, o un objeto de Firebase u otros. En cualquier caso, podrías utilizar `User` como un verdadero molde para fabricar desde cualquier contexto objetos de la clase `User`.

---

1. Para más detalles sobre esto, ver la pregunta *[¿Como se mapea el resultado de una consulta SQL a una clase en PHP usando PDO y cómo se usa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967)*  y su respuesta.

Comment: Muy bueno lo que comentas @A.Cedano. Pero,entonces sugieres que, para cada consulta sql, deberíamos crear una instancia PDO? y esto no se consideraría código duplicado? Muchas gracias

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía no, no es código duplicado. Creas una instancia PDO porque la necesitas. Si lo piensas bien, para cada instancia de `User` estás creando una instancia de PDO, dado que la conexión se crea dentro de la clase `User`, incluso el problema surgió debido a que al poner la conexión en la clase `Anuncio` estabas creando dos instancias en vez de una. Imaginemos que haya otra clase en la que también pusiste la conexión, pues son ya tres instancias de PDO y así... Todo eso explica por qué no deberías nunca crear la conexión dentro de una clase del modelo de datos.

Comment: Grande @A. Cedano, muchísimas gracias. Por gente como tú el saber llega a más personas

Comment: De nada @ÁlvaroGarcía. Para puntualizar más, imagina un contexto donde necesites crear cientos o miles de instancias de la clase `User`. Si tienes la conexión dentro de la clase, podrían estarse creando cientos o miles de conexiones a la base de datos sin necesidad ninguna.