# error al acceder una clase con el operador ::

Tags: php

error Fatal error: `Uncaught Error: Class 'accesoDB' not found in C:\laragon\www\mvcProyecto\modelo\clientes.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\mvcProyecto\modelo\clientes.php(27): clientes->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\mvcProyecto\modelo\clientes.php on line 7`

carpeta conexion - archivo conexion.php
carpeta modelo - archivo clientes.php

```
<?php
class clientes{

    protected $conexion;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexion = accesoDB::conexionbd();
    }

    public function listar(){
        $datos= array();
        $consulta = "SELECT `idCliente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `activo` FROM tblclientes ORDER BY nombre";
        echo $consulta;
        $resultado = $this->conexion->query($consulta);
        printf("La selección devolvió %d filas.\n", $resultado->num_rows);
        //Retorna una matriz fetch_assoc()
        while ($filaTmp = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $datos [] = $filaTmp;
            if($resultado){
                return $datos;
            }else{
                return 'no se encontraron datos';
            }
        }
    }
}
$validar = new clientes();
$validar->listar();
?>

<?php
    class accesoDB
    {
        function conexionbd(){
            $servidor = 'localhost';
            $usuario = 'root';
            $contraseña = '';
            $db = 'clientes';
            $conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$contraseña,$db)or die("Problemas con el servidor de BD. ");
            $conexion->set_charset('utf8');
            //echo 'correcto';
            return $conexion;
        }   
    }
    /*$validar = new accesoDB();
    $validar->conexionbd();*/
    ?>
```

Comment: creo que te falta el  requiere_once() o  el include_once()  para que sepa que quires utilizar ese archivo

Comment: El error parece ser lo que te comenta @Byro, pero, si me permites, quiero señarlar que **te estás equivocando al meter la conexión dentro de la clase `clientes`**. Una clase tiene que ser pensada como un molde donde deberías declarar únicamente aquellas propiedades que son intrínsecas de esa entidad. Una conexión no es intrínseca a `cliente` por un motivo muy simple: imaginemos que usas otra fuente para alimentar a `clientes`, digamos un archivo json, xml, un array proveniente de otro sitio. En esos 3 escenarios la conexión no pintaría nada, meterla en el constructor por tanto es erróneo.

Comment: si es incluir el archivo de conexion pero el los incluye en el controlador

Comment: Yo me refiero al constructor de tu clase `clientes`, allí tú conectas a la base de datos: `public function __construct(){
        $this->conexion = accesoDB::conexionbd();
    }` eso no es correcto porque la conexión no es algo intrínseco a la entidad `clientes`. Como ya dije, si tienes que crear instancias de clientes con datos que no vengan de la base de datos estarás también en esos casos conectando a la base de datos para nada. Tienes que pensar tus clases como un molde que te sirva para fabricar objetos de ese tipo en diversos contextos.

Comment: Cuando tengas tiempo te sugiero que leas [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967) y su respuesta. Yo la hice precisamente para arrojar luz en casos como este en que se intenta meter la lógica de la conexión dentro de una clase como `Persona, Cliente, Empleado`.

Answer (score 0):

Para php el operador "::" se utiliza solo si la clase y sus métodos son estáticos, es decir que no necesitan instanciar y están disponibles una vez el programa se ejecuta.

Según veo tienes 2 opciones:

1.- Cambiar el tipo de funcion en la clase a static como :"public static function conexionbd".

2.- Instanciar la clase accesoDB como : $miVariable= new accesoDB();  y de ahi puedes utilizar los métodos de la clase ($this->conexion = $miVariable->conexionbd();)

Prueba y me avisas:

Te dejo un link para que te orientes un poco mejor.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Le hace falta requerir el archivo que contiene la clase.

Comment: En caso de que sean documentos diferentes efectivamente de hacer esto adicionalmente de lo anteriormente descrito.

Comment: dejame lo consulto por que es un mvc que funcionaba antes

Comment: el codigo esta bien acabo de consultar con mi antiguo compañero y me falta incluir el archivo conexion, pero se hace en el controlador es donde se incluyen la conexion a la base de datos que se utilizar y los modelos  gracias.