# Pasar de String/Array de PHP a JSON

Tags: php, json

tengo un gran problema con la conversión de este array generado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A JSON, lo he intentado con todos los métodos que he encontrado por internet, pero al final siempre me devuelve un JSON vacío --> `[{},{}]`

Mi código PHP:

```
$dataSource= new DataSource();

$arraySexo= new SexoDAO($dataSource);
$arraySexo= $arraySexo->selectSexos();

echo json_encode($arraySexo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

He probado a cambiar la codificación a UTF-8 y ese no es el problema, el json_encode siempre devuelve un JSON vacío

EDIT:

El array que estoy intentando imprimir son dos objetos que me llegan de un PDO que he creado que se conecta a una BD de SQL server

Los objetos son los siguientes:

```
class Sexo{
    protected $idSexo;
    protected $sexo;

    public function __construct(){

    }
    public function toString(){
        print("<br>ID: " . $this->idSexo . "<br>");
        print("Sexo: " . $this->sexo . "<br>");
    }
    public function getIdSexo()
    {
        return $this->idSexo;
    }
    public function setIdSexo($idSexo)
    {
        $this->idSexo = $idSexo;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getSexo()
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }
    public function setSexo($sexo)
    {
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: usa json_encode($arraySexo, true);

Comment: nada, sigue igual :( me había emocionado por un momento xD

Comment: Puedes decirme que te devuelve un `var_dump($arraySexo);` justo despues de la linea `$arraySexo= $arraySexo->selectSexos();`

Comment: Y esa declaración de array es correcta? Creo que no... Yo creo que sería así: Array([[ID_Sexo] => 0, [Sexo] => Hombre])

Comment: Sin ver lo que contiene el `array` que tratas de convertir a formato **JSON** es difícil averiguar donde tienes el problema. Yo he simulado el `array` que nos muestras en la captura y `json_encode()` lo convierte sin problemas.

Comment: A lo del var_dump el resultado es:
  
  array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(Sexo)#4 (2) {
    ["idSexo":protected]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["sexo":protected]=>
    string(6) "Hombre"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Sexo)#5 (2) {
    ["idSexo":protected]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sexo":protected]=>
    string(5) "Mujer"
  }
}

Comment: Me gustaría ver cómo creas el array en el método `selectSexos()`... aunque no entiendo mucho por qué `Sexo` es un objeto en tu modelo, tampoco entiendo qué es lo que quieres obtener finalmente. El var_dump indica que te está devolviendo un array con objetos del tipo `Sexo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la definición de los atributos de clase a los que quieres acceder. Al tenerlos en `protected` no son accesibles por la función `json_encode()` devolviéndote la cadena `[{},{}]` que nos muestras.

Con poner los atributos en `public` conseguirías convertir el `array` de objetos a una cadena **JSON**.

```
class Sexo{
    public $idSexo;
    public $sexo;

    public function __construct(){

    }
    public function toString(){
        print("<br>ID: " . $this->idSexo . "<br>");
        print("Sexo: " . $this->sexo . "<br>");
    }
    public function getIdSexo()
    {
        return $this->idSexo;
    }
    public function setIdSexo($idSexo)
    {
        $this->idSexo = $idSexo;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getSexo()
    {
        return $this->sexo;
    }
    public function setSexo($sexo)
    {
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
        return $this;
    }
}

$masculino = new Sexo();
$masculino->setIdSexo(0);
$masculino->setSexo('hombre');

$femenino = new Sexo();
$femenino->setIdSexo(1);
$femenino->setSexo('mujer');

$array[0] = $masculino;
$array[1] = $femenino;

$json = json_encode($array);

var_dump($json);
```

Este es el ejemplo con el que he trabajado y te mostraría por pantalla:

```
string(58) "[{"idSexo":0,"sexo":"hombre"},{"idSexo":1,"sexo":"mujer"}]"
```

Que es la cadena en formato **JSON** que pareces necesitar.

Comment: Bien visto, pero no aconsejaría que ponga los atributos como `public`. Los miembros de la clase no quedarían encapsulados. Como dije en comentarios, me parece raro lo que el OP está haciendo. Si se trata de mapear unos resultados de una consulta, PDO [tiene una forma natural de hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967) sin necesidad de manipulaciones extrañas o de cambiar la estructura de la clase. En el ejemplo del enlace, los miembros son `private`, y los datos quedan mapeados en la clase sin ningún problema.

Comment: Lo ideal sería crear una función dentro de la clase que te devolviese el objeto en formato **JSON**, así podrías mantener los atributos en `protected`. El **public** lo puse por ejemplificar el problema.

Comment: No. La clase es un molde que sirve para fabricar objetos de ese tipo. El JSON sería lo que contiene las propiedades con que se va a llenar el molde. Yo no le veo ningún sentido a meter en una clase un método que devuelva un JSON.

Comment: No me meto en porque el usuario tenía los atributos en `protected` o en una lucha de **protected vs private**, me limito a responder a la pregunta :)

Comment: Entiendo tu punto de vista, pero yo siempre intento ir más allá. De hecho usar una clase para `Sexo` no tiene sentido, como hice saber en un comentario a la pregunta. Luego cada uno diseña como mejor le parezca pero no es malo hacer críticas constructivas, ya @elver tomara nota o no... De hecho, a mi juicio, el origen del problema aquí es ese: se está implementando un modelo de datos erróneo (**el sexo no es una clase, es un atributo**), pero ese es otro tema de discusión. El problema de tu respuesta es que enseña a declarar `public` los miembros de la clase.

Comment: No se si será recomendable, pero funciona, muchas grácias, ni se me había pasado por la cabeza que fuera eso, estaba mirando hacia otro lado.