# Transformar el resultado de una consulta a un objeto

Tags: php, pdo

Quiero tratar los resultados de mis consultas SQL como `object` en vez de `array`. Recuerdo que existía una forma para armarlo desde la consulta con `PDO` pero ahora no recuerdo. Encontré esta forma de hacerlo pero no me parece para nada eficiente ya que recibo un `object` lo convierto a `array` y luego a `object` de nuevo.

Ejemplo sin mucho adorno:

```
<?php

class FakeSubscriber
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($connection)
    {
        $this->conn = $connection;

    }

    public function getFakeSubs()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM fakesubscribers";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
class FakeSubscribersController
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $con = new Connection();
        $this->conn = $con->connect();
    }

    public function showSubs()
    {
        $subs = new FakeSubscriber($this->conn);

        return $subs->getFakeSubs();
    }

}
```

Y en la supuesta vista, para manejarlo como objeto lo hago así ya que cuando envió el resultado a un foreach me lo convierte a `array`

```
$fs = new FakeSubscribersController();

$allS = $fs->showSubs();

foreach ($allS as $all) {
    $all = (object) $all;
    echo $all->subscriber_name . "\n";
}
```

Utilizo `(object)` para convertir el `array` a `object`, recuerdo que había una forma para traerlo como `object` sin necesidad de convertirlo de la forma en la que lo estoy haciendo.

Comment: Asumo que `FakeSubscriber` es una entidad de tu modelo de datos (que puede estar representada o no por una tabla en la base de datos). Si es así hay en tu código un error de concepto en cuanto al alcance real de la POO. Lo suyo sería diseñar una clase que represente a esa entidad en términos realmente metafísicos, entiéndase únicamente con **las propiedades intrínsecas de su ser `FakeSubscriber` y nada más**. Significaría en 1er lugar sacar la conexión del constructor de esa clase y quizá incluso sacar de ahí el `getFakeSubs()`, dotando a esa clase de lo que es suyo (cada columna en la ...

Comment: ... tabla `fakesubscribers`). Luego entonces podrás mapear los resultados de una consulta SQL  a esa clase mediante un método específico de PDO que sirve para eso. El contexto en el que se lanza la consulta y se mapean los datos dependerá de cómo tengas organizado el código, podría ser un controlador o desde otro sitio. Tu error (de lógica) aquí es querer meter en la clase que debe representar a la entidad en sí código y métodos que pertenecen a la lógica de negocio. (Ver [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967) y su respuesta, donde intenté abordar un problema parecido).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes valerte del método [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) ya que estás usando PDO para:

- Generar una matriz de datos los cuales serán todas las filas que tu consulta recupere y que estarán bajo la estructura de array, modificando tu query a algo como esto:

  ```
  $resultados = $stmt->fetchAll();
  ```

Una vez que eso esta hecho, para poder convertir cada uno de esos arrays internos en objetos podemos hacer uso del parámetro [`PDO::FETCH_OBJ`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) de esta forma:

```
  $resultados = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Que como puedes consultar en la propia doc. (*provista en el enlace*) te regresará:

- Un objeto anónimo
- Las claves de dicho objeto anónimo se corresponden a los nombres de las columnas que tu `SELECT` determinó traer

Al final para iterar los valores, lo haces por medio de un foreach y de la sintaxis de: **`$variable->clave`** para obtener los valores deseados:

```
foreach ($resultados as $fila) {
    echo $fila->clave;
}
```

Y ya no necesitarías hacer un *cast* de valores como al momento lo llevas a cabo