# Web service con PHP devuelve array no JSON

Tags: php, android, json

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación android, quiero consumir un servicio web.
Tengo 2 archivos, el primero la conexión a la base de datos

```
<?php
    class Conexion extends PDO
    {
        private $hostname = 'localhost';
        private $database = 'base';
        private $username = 'root';
        private $password = '';

        public function __construct(){
            try{
                parent::__construct('mysql:host='.$this->hostname.'; dbname='.$this->database.';charset=utf8', $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
            } catch(PDOException $e){
                echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

y el archivo donde mando a llamar esta clase es la siguiente

```
<?php
    include 'C:/xampp/htdocs/poa_ws/conectar.php';
    $pdo = new Conexion();

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
        if(isset($_GET['num_actividad_extra'])){
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividad_extra WHERE num_actividad_extra =:num_actividad_extra");
            $sql->bindValue(':num_actividad_extra',$_GET['num_actividad_extra']);
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll());
            exit;
        }else{
            $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividad_extra");
            $sql->execute();
            $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($sql->fetchAll());
            exit;
        } 
    }
?>
```

al momento de probar el Webservice me devuelve lo siguiente

```
[{"id":1,"num_actividad_extra":1,"detalle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed sunt quia id iure iure quo natus placeat sit laboriosam voluptatibus ut illo nihil non pariatur placeat et mollitia accusamus? Aut eveniet quia in perferendis autem eos optio error quo repudiandae mollitia qui explicabo asp","fecha":"0000-00-00","responsable":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame","comentarios":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed sunt quia id iure iure quo natus placeat sit laboriosam voluptatibus ut illo nihil non pariatur placeat et mollitia accusamus? Aut eveniet quia in perferendis autem eos optio error quo repudiandae mollitia qui explicabo asp"}]
```

Lo cual es correcto, pero al momento de realizar la conexión con Android Studio me devuelve el error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app_poa, PID: 17461
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":1,"num_actividad_extra":1,"detalle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed sunt quia id iure iure quo natus placeat sit laboriosam voluptatibus ut illo nihil non pariatur placeat et mollitia accusamus? Aut eveniet quia in perferendis autem eos optio error quo repudiandae mollitia qui explicabo asp","fecha":"0000-00-00","responsable":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame","comentarios":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed sunt quia id iure iure quo natus placeat sit laboriosam voluptatibus ut illo nihil non pariatur placeat et mollitia accusamus? Aut eveniet quia in perferendis autem eos optio error quo repudiandae mollitia qui explicabo asp"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

por lo cual, buscando encontré que es por que el Webservice no arroja un objeto Json, si no un array.
pero ya busque e intente muchas cosas, para las cuales nunguna me ha funcionado hasta el momento, me pueden ayudar?
llevo ya 3 días con esto :c

Intenté hacer el cambio de version de PHP, quitar los corchetes en android studio, ocupar los metodos de PDO pero no me funciona :c

he agregado tambien la clausula content-type: application/json
header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Primero de todo prueba con postman u otra aplicación parecida, la petición de tu PHP. Así puedes descartar si es cosa de PHP que no te devuelva un Json correcto. Si te devuelve uno correcto, entonces mira como lo lees desde Android, quizás es más ese el problema.

Comment: Te da como resultado un arreglo de objetos por lo que no respeta el formato permitido por android, revisa esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/396342/transformar-el-resultado-de-una-consulta-a-un-objeto) te puede servir.

Comment: La parte de PHP yo la veo bien... Quizas el error esta es en como estas llamando el endpoint desde android y como estas obteniendo el resultado. Podrias poner ese código?

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, lo que sucede es que en realidad es un JsonArray y tu tratas de obtener la información como JsonObject, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simple, recuerda lo siguiente:

- Si el .json inicia con **{** se considera como objeto Json.
- Si el .json inicia con **[** es considerado como Arreglo Json.

por lo tanto si analizas tu respuesta:

> [{"id":1,"num_actividad_extra":1,"detalle":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit
> amet. Sed sunt quia id iure iure quo natus placeat sit laboriosam
> voluptatibus ut illo nihil non pariatur placeat et mollitia accusamus?
> Aut eveniet quia in perferendis autem eos optio error quo repudiandae
> mollitia qui explicabo asp","fecha":"0000-00-00","responsable":"Lorem
> ipsum dolor sit ame","comentarios":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Sed
> sunt quia id iure iure quo natus placeat sit laboriosam voluptatibus
> ut illo nihil non pariatur placeat et mollitia accusamus? Aut eveniet
> quia in perferendis autem eos optio error quo repudiandae mollitia qui
> explicabo asp"}]

El .json inicia con `[`, por lo tanto se considera como un arreglo Json, pero  seguramente estas usando la clase `JSONObject(respuestaJson)`, lo cual es incorrecto y por esta razón obtienes el error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: Value
> [{"id":1,"num_actividad_extra":1,...."fecha":"0000-00-asp"}] of type
> org.json.**JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject**

**En este caso debes usar la clase `JSONArray`**:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(respuestaJson);
```