# Cómo mostrar con Value Objects los campos de dos tablas

Tags: php

Por ejemplo tengo dos tablas: Trabajador y Planilla
Y cada tabla tiene su respectivo Value Object con setters y getters.

```
class TrabajadorVO {
    private $_id;
    private $_nom;
    private $_ape;
    private $_fecnac;
(...)

class PlanillaVO {
private $_id;
private $_area;
private $_sueldo;
private $_fecing;
(...)
```

Y en una consulta quiero mostrar los registros de ambas tablas relacionados por el id que es común.

```
$sql = "SELECT  a.id, a.nom, a.ape, a.fecnac, b.area, b.sueldo, b.fecing
        FROM    trabajador a,
                planilla b
        WHERE   a.id = b.id";
```

Pero cómo los asigno a un Value Object?
Tengo que crear otro VO consolidado para cada consulta que necesite?

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $registroVO = new TrabajadorVO();  // Aquí instancio el VO de Trabajador pero no de Planilla
    $registroVO->set_id( $row['id'] );
    $registroVO->set_nom( $row['nom'] );
    $registroVO->set_ape( $row['ape'] );
    $registroVO->set_fecnac( $row['fecnac'] );

    $registros[] = $registroVO;
}
```

Comment: A ver creo que hay algún error de planteamiento. Trabajador seguramente es una entidad de dominio y no un VO, esta entidad de dominio Trabajador debería contener un VO de plantilla. Los VO deberían ser inmutables, no deben tener setters. Una vez que tengas claro cuál es tu entidad y cuáles son sus VO, necesitas intanciar primero los VO para posteriormente construir/instanciar la entidad.

Comment: Pero si no tienen __setters__ como asigno el valor a la variable para mostrarla en la vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé a qué te refieres con esto: *¿Tengo que crear otro VO consolidado para cada consulta que necesite?*

Si quieres llenar tu clase `PlanillaVO` con sus respectivos datos, tienes que crear una instancia de esa clase y llenarla con los *setter*, como haces con `TrabajadorVO` y luego meter esa instancia en `registros`.

Por ejemplo:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    /*Simplificamos el nombrado para este contexto*/
    $t = new TrabajadorVO();
    $t->set_id( $row['id'] );
    $t->set_nom( $row['nom'] );
    $t->set_ape( $row['ape'] );
    $t->set_fecnac( $row['fecnac'] );

    $p=new PlanillaVO();
    $p->set_id( $row['id'] );
    /*Doy por supuesto que los setter se llaman así ...*/
    $p->set_area( $row['area'] );
    $p->set_sueldo( $row['sueldo'] );
    $p->set_fecing( $row['fecing'] );
    $registros[] = array('trabajador'=>$t, 'planilla'=>$p);
}

#Test
var_dump($registros);
```

### Post-Data

PDO te permite mapear los resultados de una consulta a una clase<sup>1</sup>, lo cual es bastante útil para clases simples. Pero ese mapeo no escala entre clases, para casos como la herencia por ejemplo. Usando un ORM podrías fácilmente mapear resultados como estos, llenando cada instancia respectiva, pero refinando el modelo de datos.

---

1. Ver la pregunta: [¿Como se mapea el resultado de una consulta SQL a una clase en PHP usando PDO y cómo se usa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967)

Comment: No sabía que se podía hacer de esa manera, por lo menos la generación me funcionó aunque todavía tengo dudas al recuperar los valores, porque son objetos. Probaré.