# Warning: Attempt to read property PHP

Tags: php, crud

Buen día

Estoy realizando un formulario en PHP, marcha bien pero tengo un error al consultar tablas que no arrojan datos:

Warning: Attempt to read property "Comunidad_Indigena" on bool in ....

Esto se debe a que no encuentra el ID en la base, y es correcto, ya que no todos los ID cuentan con esa info. Ya intente resolverlo con una condicional, pero sin exito.

Parte del codigo es:

```
class Expediente {
private function Idioma($ID)

{
    $stm = query("SELECT * FROM Idioma WHERE ID = '$ID'");
    $stm->execute();
    $stm->execute();
    return  $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}

public function Idioma-Form($ID) {   
    $idioma = $this->Idioma($ID);
    $this->Idioma = $idioma->Idioma;
 }
```

Todo esto va con mas tablas dentro de una clase que es la que llamo al formulario
Alguien puede ayudarme a resolver como puede quedar la condicional?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Veo varias cosas en tu código:

1. Los dos métodos que muestras son redundantes. Con un solo método puedes obtener el idioma y retornarlo.
2. En el primer método estás escribiendo un código vulnerabable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Cuando puedas lee sobre el tema y sobre *consultas preparadas*. Tu servidor podría quedar gravemente expuesto si escribes código vulnerable. Dado que usas una propiedad `$stmt` que no sé de dónde la sacas, no puedo escribirte un código seguro aquí, pero conviene que uses tu conexión para preparar la consulta.
3. En tu primer método estás usando `execute()` dos veces. Realmente no necesitas `execute()`, porque estás usando `query()`, que es una modalidad de `execute()` pero NO segura en este caso, por lo ya dicho en (2).
4. Para controlar el resultado de tu consulta debes hacerlo fuera de clase. Conviene que tengas en la cabeza algo así como un *contrato* y que lo reflejes en tu código. Ejemplo de *contrato*: ***devolverá `false` cuando no haya idioma***. Dicho eso, donde recibes los datos verificas si la respuesta es `false` o no, y en la clase, devuelves `false` cuando no haya idiomas. Este es el comportamiento de `fetch()` cuando no hay datos. En un programa más maduro, puedes por ejemplo mandar un array con una clave `error` y un mensaje, para controlar los errores. Pero ese ya es otro asunto...

Aplicando lo dicho, tu clase podría quedar así:

```
class Expediente {    

    private function getIdiomaById($ID)
    {
        $stm = query("SELECT * FROM Idioma WHERE ID = '$ID'");
        $rs=$stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        /*
           Asumo que:
             1. Hay una columna llamada Idioma en tu tabla Idioma
             2. Tu clase tiene una propiedad llamada Idioma
          Verificaremos si $rs no es false
          para setear la propiedad idioma y devolverla
          de lo contrario, devolveremos false
          Y en la llamada (código al final de la respuesta)
          verificaremos el estado de lo que el
          método haya devuelto: el idioma, o false
        */
        if ($rs) 
        {
            $this->Idioma = $rs->Idioma;
            return $this->Idioma;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

Y desde donde llamas el método:

```
# $mExpediente es una instancia de la clase Expediente
# en un contexto cualquiera
$idioma=$mExpediente->getIdiomaById($ID);
if ($idioma)
{
    #Usar $idioma
} else {
    #Idioma es false, no hay idioma, actuar en consecuencia
}
```

#### P.D.

Considera que en PDO puedes mapear una clase a un resultado (ver la pregunta [¿Como se mapea el resultado de una consulta SQL a una clase en PHP usando PDO y cómo se usa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967)), quizá convenga hacer esto en tu contexto para simplificar el código. Sacando de dentro de tu clase `Expediente` la conexión a PDO. Las clases de entidad deberían ser pensadas como moldes que usas para construir modelos de esos datos, y no deberían arrastar consigo la conexión.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, lo solucione con un if como comentas.
Soy administrador de bases de datos, se encargo un CRUD a un programador PHP, eso fue lo que nos entrego, actualmente me encuentro agregando mas campos, corrigiendo errores y ordenando el codigo, primera vez que trabajo con PHP.  
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con lo que me comentas creo vale encargar a otra persona la seguridad y orden del código.