# Consulta sql devuelve un boolean y no un objeto

Tags: php, sql, objeto, booleano

cuando intento mostrar datos de una tabla me aparece este error:Warning: Attempt to read property "nombre_cancion" on bool

la consulta es esta:

```
function getCancion($id){
        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT a.*, b.* FROM canciones a INNER JOIN artistas b ON a.nombre_artista = b.nombre_artista WHERE id_cancion = ?');
        $query->execute([$id]);       
        $cancion = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $cancion;
    }
```

y asi trato de acceder a los datos:
`<h1><?=$cancion->nombre_cancion;?></h1>`

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que esta mal con la sonsulta?

Comment: Significa que la consulta a la base de datos está devolviendo `false`. Verifica si la consulta está correcta o si no está trayendo registros porque el `id` que no existe. En ese caso tendrás que manejar la excepción *[no hay canciones con ese id]*. Por otro lado el `JOIN` me parece extraño, porque ¿tienes el nombre del artista en ambas tablas? Debería ser `id_artista` el cual es un dato numérico entero.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Warning: Attempt to read property PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/524384/warning-attempt-to-read-property-php)

Answer (score 0):

Estás cometiendo el error de intentar acceder a la propiedad de un objeto sin verificar el estado de dicho objeto.

Dado que [**`fetch()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) devuelve **`false`** si no encuentra datos o si hubo algún error, puedes hacer la verificación de este modo:

```
if($cancion) {
    // Hay fiesta
} else {
    // No hay fiesta, lo siento
}
```

Más cosas:

- Podrías retornar directamente el resultado de `fetch()`, no es necesario en ese contexto reservar espacio de  memoria para una variable.
- Deberías evitar la forma abreviada de PHP. [El Manual dice claramente](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#language.basic-syntax.phptags) que esa forma no es recomendable, primero, porque para que funcione debes modificar el archivo `php.ini` y segundo, por problemas de compatibilidad:

  > PHP también permite la etiqueta de apertura abreviada `<?` (la cual
  > está desaconsejada debido a que sólo está disponible si se habilita
  > con la directiva `short_open_tag` del fichero de configuración
  > `php.ini`, o si PHP se configuró con la opción `--enable-short-tags`).

Aplicando las mejoras sugeridas, tu código puede quedar así, nótese que el uso de `printf()` o `sprintf()` según el caso, son una alternativa mucho más limpia que usar etiquetas de apertura abreviada.

#### Método

```
function getCancion($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT a.*, b.* FROM canciones a INNER JOIN artistas b ON a.nombre_artista = b.nombre_artista WHERE id_cancion = ?');
    $query->execute([$id]);       
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

#### Donde consumes la respuesta

```
<?php

    //Lo que sea de código
    $id=1;
    $cancion=getCancion($id);
    if($cancion)
    {
        printf('<h1>%s</h1>',$cancion->nombre_cancion);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No hay canción";
    }
```

O si quieres, para algo sencillo como esto, en lugar de `printf`, puedes simplemente usar comillas dobles y meter dentro la llamada al objeto y su propiedad, algo así:

```
echo "<h1>{$cancion->nombre_cancion}</h1>";
```

Cualquiera de las dos es más limpia y más compatible que usar la forma abreviada.