# Error array indefinido lectura usuarios PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Al realizar la consulta de contar los usuarios me aparece estos errores, esta consulta debe de entrar en repositorio usuarios y establecerme los datos de cada usuario que hay, si hago un var_dump me sale lo siguiente:

array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["ID"]=> int(1) [0]=> int(1) ["NOMBRE"]=> string(6) "Ismael" [1]=> string(6) "Ismael" ["EMAIL"]=> string(30) "Ismaelmontoyacollado@gmail.com" [2]=> string(30) "Ismaelmontoyacollado@gmail.com" ["PASSWORD"]=> string(4) "1234" [3]=> string(4) "1234" ["FECHA_REGISTRO"]=> string(19) "2022-06-02 13:09:13" [4]=> string(19) "2022-06-02 13:09:13" ["ACTIVO"]=> int(1) [5]=> int(1) } }

> Warning: Undefined array key "id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 21

> Warning: Undefined array key "nombre" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 22

> Warning: Undefined array key "email" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 23

> Warning: Undefined array key "password" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 24

> Warning: Undefined array key "fecha_registro" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 25

> Warning: Undefined array key "activo" in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 26

Codigo Pagina:

```
<?php

include_once "app/Conexion.inc.php";
include_once "app/RepositorioUsuario.inc.php";

Conexion :: abrir_conexion();
//Hacemos que usuarios sea igual a obtener todos, lo alimentamos con la conexion obtener conexion
$usuarios = RepositorioUsuario :: obtenerTodos(Conexion::obtener_conexion());
//Escribir nuemor de usuario para ver si funciona
echo count($usuarios);

Conexion :: cerrar_conexion();

?>
```

Codigo repositorio usuario:

```
<?php

class RepositorioUsuario{
    public static function obtenerTodos($conexion){
        $usuarios = array();
        if (isset($conexion)){
            try {
                include_once "Usuario.inc.php";

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
                //Ejecutar sentencia sql
                $sentencia -> execute();
                //que devuelva los resultados
                $resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll();

var_dump($resultado);
                    if(count($resultado)){
                        foreach($resultado as $fila){
                            $usuarios[] = new Usuario(
                                $fila["id"],
                                $fila["nombre"],
                                $fila["email"],
                                $fila["password"],
                                $fila["fecha_registro"],
                                $fila["activo"]
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        print "No hay usuarios";
                    }
                } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    print "ERROR".$ex -> getMessage();
                }
            }
            //Devolvemos el array de usuarios
            return $usuarios;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Usuario.inc.php:

```
<?php
    class Usuario {
        private $id;
        private $nombre;
        private $email;
        private $password;
        private $fecha_registro;

        public function __construct($id, $nombre, $email, $password, $fecha_registro, $activo){
            //El atributo de la clase es el mismo al q pasamos al constructor
            $this -> id = $id;
            $this -> nombre = $nombre;
            $this -> email = $email;
            $this -> password = $password;
            $this -> fecha_registro = $fecha_registro;
            $this -> activo = $activo;
        }

        public function obtenerId(){
            return $this -> id;
        }

        public function obtenerNombre(){
            return $this -> nombre;
        }

        public function obtenerEmail(){
            return $this -> email;
        }

        public function obtenerPassword(){
            return $this -> password;
        }

        public function obtenerFechaRegistro(){
            return $this -> fecha_registro;
        }

        public function esta_activo(){
            return $this -> activo;
        }

        public function cambiarNombre($nombre){
            $this -> nombre = $nombre;    
        }

        public function cambiarEmail($email){
            $this -> email = $email;
        }

        public function cambiarPassword($password){
            $this -> password = $password;    
        }

        public function cambiarActivo($activo){
            $this -> activo = $activo;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Antes del ciclo agrega la siguiente línea: `var_dump($resultado);` Eso te va a permitir ver el contenido del arreglo, solo revisa que cada índice corresponda, respetando mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Tu pregunta es bastante pobre, no nos dices que es lo que te pasa, no dices que línea es la que falla.... por favor pulsa en [edit] y aclara mejor tu pregunta

Comment: Aclarada, es q no sabia como explicarla, lo mismo es por algun include o algo.

Comment: recuerda que en php las mayusculas son importantes, noto que en indice que tu array vienen en mayuscula y tu estas consultando los indices en minuscula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En PHP los nombres de clave de arrays son *case sensitive*, significa que si la clave es `ID` en el array, no puedes intentar leerlo así: `$elArray['id']`, sino que debes ponerlo así: `$elArray['ID']`.

Dicho eso, estás desperdiciando recursos, leyendo y releyendo los datos. Puedes indicar en `fetchAll()` que quieres un array asociativo, y usar ese array, sin necesidad de recrear otro array.

Es más, para este caso, dado que tienes una clase `Usuario`, puedes mapear las filas a instancias de esa clase, mediante

```
$sentencia->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');
```

Es decir, en vez de esto:

```
            $resultado = $sentencia -> fetchAll();

var_dump($resultado);
                if(count($resultado)){
                    foreach($resultado as $fila){
                        $usuarios[] = new Usuario(
                            $fila["id"],
                            $fila["nombre"],
                            $fila["email"],
                            $fila["password"],
                            $fila["fecha_registro"],
                            $fila["activo"]
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    print "No hay usuarios";
                }
```

Puedes simplificar bastante haciendo esto:

```
$sentencia->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');
$allUsers=array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
        $allUsers[]=$row;
}
```

`$allUsers` será un array de objetos del tipo `Usuario`, y para verificar su estado puedes hacer:

```
if($allUsers) {
    #Usar el array de objetos
}
else
}
    print('No hay datos');
}
```

Sobre mapear resultados desde PDO a clases, puedes consultar también esta pregunta: *[¿Como se mapea el resultado de una consulta SQL a una clase en PHP usando PDO y cómo se usa?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967)*.

Comment: No logro entender el funcionamiento $sentencia->setFecthMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');   Ademas que la variable result(resultado) no la tendria iniciada y nose como establecerlo.

Comment: @IsmaelMontoya tienes que cambiar `$result`  por `$sentencia` en el código. Y lo que hace `$sentencia->setFecthMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Usuario');` es indicar que los resultados sean mapeados a instancias de la clase `Usuario` que ya tienes definida.

Comment: Perfecto, me has resuelto el problema por completo, tenia yo un poco fallo después pero solucionado, muchas gracias.