# Como puedo mostrar varias instancias dentro de la tabla en php

Tags: php, poo, objeto

tengo una clase persona que, tiene constructor, getter y setter, luego creo a varias personas, y lo que quiero hacer es meter en un array las 4 instancias, para recorrer con un bucle y que los datos se vayan introduciendo en una tabla, para que los muestre.

Pero me da un error, en concreto este error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class Persona could not be converted to string in C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\PHP\PHP_Orientado_Objetos\personas.php:95 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\PHP\PHP_Orientado_Objetos\personas.php(102): bucle(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\PHP\PHP_Orientado_Objetos\personas.php on line 95

Este es el código completo:

```
 ` <?php
class Persona
 {
 private $nombre, $apellidos, $email;

function __construct($nombre, $apellidos, $email)
{
    $this->nombre = $nombre;
    $this->apellidos = $apellidos;
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getNombre()
{
    return $this->nombre;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $nombre 
 * @return self
 */
public function setNombre($setNombre): self
{
    $this->nombre = $setNombre;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getApellidos()
{
    return $this->apellidos;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $apellidos 
 * @return self
 */
public function setApellidos($setApellidos): self
{
    $this->apellidos = $setApellidos;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $email 
 * @return self
 */
public function setEmail($setEmail): self
{
    $this->email = $setEmail;
    return $this;
}
// function __toString(){
//     return "Nombre: ".$this->nombre."<br>Apellidos".$this->apellidos;
// }
}

 $persona1 = new Persona("JOEL", "MENESES", "JJ@HOTMAIL.COM");
 $persona2 = new Persona("SARA", "BAQUERO", "BB@HOTMAIL.COM");
 $persona3 = new Persona("JORGE", "MAQUEDA", "JORGE@HOTMAIL.COM");
 $persona4 = new Persona("ANDRES", "ANDRES", "ANDRES@HOTMAIL.COM");
 $arrayPersona = array ($persona1,$persona2,$persona3,$persona4);
 $arrayPersona[]=$persona1;
 $arrayPersona[]=$persona2;
 $arrayPersona[]=$persona3;
 $arrayPersona[]=$persona4;

function bucle($persona): Void
 {
 echo "<table>" .
    "<thead>" .
        "<tr>" .
        "<th>NOMBRE</th>" .
        "<th>APELLIDOS</th>" .
        "<th>EMAIL</th>" .
        "</tr>" .
    "</thead>" .
    "<tbody>" .
        "<tr>";
foreach ($persona as $key => $value) {
    echo "<th>" . $value . "</th>";
}
echo "</tr>" .
    "</tbody>" .
   "</table>";
       }

       bucle($arrayPersona);`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema viene porque estás intentando pintar el objeto `Persona` en este punto:

```
foreach ($persona as $key => $value) {
    echo "<th>" . $value . "</th>";
}
```

Tendrías que pintar las propiedades por separado, o pintar la propiedad que quieras. En este caso `$value` es el objeto `Persona`.
Por lo que por ejemplo si quisieras pintar el nombre, tendrías que poner:

```
foreach ($persona as $key => $value) {
    echo "<th>" . $value->getNombre() . "</th>";
}
```

Si quieres, podrías definir una función `__toString()` en la clase `Persona` para poder hacer `echo` al objeto directamente, y en esa función se detectará como deberá pintarse como String ese objeto.
Ejemplo:

```
function __toString()
{
   return $this->getNombre() . ' ' . $this->getApellidos();
}
```

(Con esto último solamente, ya funcionaría tu código también)

Comment: Dado que OP quiere una tabla donde cada dato es una celda, falta completar eso dentro del `foreach`, y no debería usar `th` sino `td`, pues los datos no deben ser encabezados (`th`)  sino datos normales (`td`).

Comment: Así es más simple: `foreach ($persona as $key => $value) {
    printf( "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",$value->getNombre(),$value->getApellidos(),$value->getEmail() );
}`  Y **quitar el `<tr> ... </tr>` que tiene por fuera del `foreach`**.

Comment: A.Cedano muchas gracias resolvi la duda, ahora me pinta todos los datos en una tabla

Comment: cnbandicoot muchas gracias, si lo puedo hacer con un tostring de hecho lo tengo comentado, porque queria pintar los datos en una tabla, pero gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Una pregunta, como podría traer los datos de un json, instanciar cada dato y luego pintarlo en la tabla??

Comment: @informaticoDudas si los datos vienen de una base de datos no necesitas pasarlos a JSON, pues PDO y mysqli te pueden mapear cada fila a instancias de una clase ([ver por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/233094/29967)). Si es un JSON que viene de una API o de otro lado, te recomendaría que uses una librería para mapear el JSON a los POJO de tu modelo de datos.