# Herencia de atributos en PHP

Tags: php, herencia

Tengo dos clases `clase1` y `clase2`. `clase2` hereda de `clase1`, ¿hay alguna forma de que al enviar el `objeto2` por json solo se muestren sus atributos y no los de la clase padre?

```php
    class ClasePadre
    {
        protected $idPadre;
    }


    class ClaseHija extends ClasePadre
    {
        private $idHija;
    }

    $ch = new ClaseHija();

    print_r($ch);
```

Me regresa lo siguiente:

```php
ClaseHija Object ( [idHija:ClaseHija:private] => [idPadre:protected] => )
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que solo regrese `idHija` y no las propiedades heredadas?

Comment: Es tal cual como lo tienes, pero `print_r($ch);` no regresa un JSON, para regresar un json debes hacer `echo json_encode($ch);`

Comment: si, lo sé, solo era para mostrar lo que me regresa, intenté con unset pero me da error

Comment: Entonces no entiendo tu problema ese código y usando `json_encode` no te va a retornar ni `$idPadre` ni `$idHija` porque el primero es `protected` y el 2do es `private`

Comment: ok, tengo una clase Model en la cual tiene propiedades protected y de esa clase hereda el User (modelo) estos archivos son para consultas a la base de datos, entonces al regresar el registro lo que hago es usar PDO::FETCH_CLASS pero a parte de regresarme los datos de la consulta me regresa las propiedades de la clase Model como es protected $table protected $primaryKey. Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Y si lo conviertes a JSON y lo vuelves a convertir a objeto? --> `json_decode(json_encode($ch));`

Comment: ok, voy a probar

Comment: Excelente, funcionó. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Quizá lo que ocurre aquí es que no estás entendiendo el sentido de la herencia, uno de los conceptos más sólidos de la POO. Si `Hija` extiende de `Padre`, debería ocurrir justamente lo que dices no querer que ocurra. Es más, en tu clase dado que el `id` es una propiedad común a ambas clases, deberías pasarlo a `Padre`, no dejarlo en `Hija`. Eso es totalmente contradictorio con la herencia. En la clase `Hija` deben quedarse únicamente las propiedades que no son de la clase `Padre`.

Comment: Si, si entiendo la herencia y es exactamente lo que hace mi código, pero debe haber una forma de solo regresar los datos de tabla que se consulta como objeto user algo así como lo que hace laravel si usas el método find te devuelve un objeto de tipo user solo con los datos de la consulta, eso es lo que intento hacer.

Comment: el regresar el json nuevamente a objeto funciona pero el único problema es que ahora el objeto es de tipo stdclass y eso no es lo que busco. Espero me haya explicado bien

Comment: Eso ya lo hará si usas `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, pero debes tener los *getter* y *setter* declarados en tu clase. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233095/29967) y el ejemplo de código que hay en ella.

Comment: Y sobre todo: los nombres de columna de la tabla deben coincidir con los nombres de las propiedades de la clase, para que el mapeo ocurra. Si no es el caso, puedes hacer que coincidan usando `AS` en la consulta SQL, o bien renombrar las propiedades de la clase o las columnas, lo que más te convenga.

Comment: justo eso hice, use __set y __get y con eso funcionó